# How to solve congruence equations with powers?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm wondering if there are efficient methods to solve equations such as:

$$ x^{30} = 7 \pmod{83} $$

Where the exponent is some arbitrarily high number.

Thanks!

Comment: $15\times11\equiv1\bmod82$, so $y^{15}\equiv7\bmod83$ has solution $y\equiv (y^{15})^{11}\equiv7^{11}\equiv64\bmod83$, so $x\equiv\pm8\bmod83$

Comment: but how is that related to the exponent 30?

Comment: If $y=x^2$, then $y^{15}=x^{30}$